# « Casser la tête »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, france

*La Petite Fadette*, George Sand

> Fadette se changeait en un grelet gros
> comme une chèvre, et elle lui criait, en voix de
> grelet, une chanson qu’il ne pouvait comprendre,
> mais où il entendait toujours des mots sur la
> même rime : grelet, fadet, cornet, capet, follet,
> bessonnet, Sylvinet. **Il en avait la tête cassée**, et la
> clarté du follet lui semblait si vive et si prompte
> que, quand il s’éveilla, il en avait encore les
> orblutes, qui sont petites boules noires, rouges ou
> bleues, lesquelles nous semblent être devant nos
> yeux, quand nous avons regardé avec trop
> d’assurance les orbes du soleil ou de la lune.

<sub>**Note** : « qui sont *des* petites boules noires » est la traduction moderne ; certains mots grammaticaux (comme les pronoms relatifs objet) ne sont pas utilisés dans le texte de Sand, mais je ne sais pas si c'était une pratique courante de son temps.</sub>

L'expression « casser la tête » telle qu'utilisée dans l'histoire de Sand signifie apparemment « casser les oreilles ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/casser)) b) [L'accent est mis sur la fatigue physique ou morale, le découragement] Au fig. **Casser bras et jambes à qqn**. (Lar. 19e, Lar. encyclop., Rob.). Enlever tout courage, anéantir. **Casser les bras à**. Ça vous casserait les bras de l'amener jusqu'ici [une valise]? (Aymé, La Mouche bleue,1957, p. 81). **Casser la tête à**. Ses bavardages me cassent la tête (R. Martin du Gard, Les Thibault,Épilogue, 1940, p. 945).**Casser les oreilles**. Tais-toi un moment, bon dieu! Tu nous casses les oreilles (Sartre, La Mort dans l'âme,1949, p. 106).

Il me semble que ces expressions  ne doivent pas être utilisées de nos jours dans un arrangement différent de celui qu'elles ont dans un dictionnaire. Par exemple je n'ai jamais lu ou entendu quelque chose comme « Elle l'écoutait avec des oreilles cassées. ». Est-ce correct ?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Translating into English, the expression "Tais-toi un moment, bon dieu! Tu nous casses les oreilles" makes perfect sense, — "be quiet a while; you're going to break our ears," even though the expression "break our ears" isn't used in English. But the translation of "Elle l'écoutait avec des oreilles cassées" — "she was listening with broken ears" would leave me baffled. Why should it be any different in French?

Comment: @PeterShor That is nothing more than typical of Sand's construction; in her construction she changes the idiom from "qqn1 V (casser) O (oreilles, tête) à qqn2"  to  "qqn2 V (avoir) (oreille, tête) + ADJ (cassée) [missing] par qqn1". This is quite different: "(TLFi) II.− Verbe copule de loc. verbales. Le verbe _avoir_ représente l'élément verbal d'une locution exprimant une manière d'être momentanée, occasionnelle ou permanente.". "cassée" is essentially an adjective (participial adjective). Do not think there is a conjugated tense (avoir … cassée), it is not so. (1/2)

Comment: @PeterShor "Après  avoir cassé la tête à sa mère pendant une heure il a finalement eu ce qu'il voulait." is correct today: the idiom is in the "infinitif passé". As well you can use it in the infinitive. "Casser la tête aux gens n'est pas la meilleure  façon d'en tirer quelque chose de  productif." (2/2)

Comment: Judging only by analogy to English, I don't see anything special about whether *cassée* is an adjective or a verb. In English, maybe a translation of *"Il en avait la tête cassée"* might be *"All that racket has left me with broken ears,"* which doesn't seem so different to me from *"All that noise has broken my ears."* But *"Elle l'écoutait avec des oreilles cassées" — "she was listening with broken ears"* seems much farther from the original idiom, and thus starts to border on the incomprehensible. Of course, not being a fluent French speaker, I could be totally wrong about this.

Comment: @PeterShor 1/ First, you are neglecting that there is a change of structure "qqn1 V (casser) O (oreilles, tête) à qqn2" to "qqn2 V (avoir) (oreille, tête) + ADJ (cassée) [missing] par qqn1". This is quite different: "(TLFi) II.− Verbe copule de loc. verbales. Le verbe _avoir_ représente l'élément verbal d'une locution exprimant une manière d'être momentanée, occasionnelle ou permanente.". This change of structure is common if you are not dealing with idioms ("Joseph a (_auxiliaire_) cassé une jambe à Jean.", Jean a (_copule_)  une jambe cassée."). With idioms it is not the  (1/4)

Comment: @PeterShor case, usually. This is what I thought, but as I found this example showing the contrary it becomes interesting to have the say of other people who might have some solid information on the matter. 2/ In English, considering a statement of fact such as "One of those situations had come to a head.", you can certainly not say " The situation come to a head was now being discussed.", so stringent and variegated are  the restrictions imposed by idioms. The grammatical context is similar: now "come" is the past participle of "come" used adjectivally. Instead, you have (2/4)

Comment: @PeterShor   to use a conjugated form: "The situation **that had** come to a head was now being discussed.". There is however no problem with this case: "One of those situations was brought to a head."; now you can say " The situation brought to a head was now being discussed.". The grammatical context for the "come" example  is similar to the "casser" example in French: now "come" is the past participle of "come" used adjectivally. As bizarre as it seems you can say "the man came to life." and "The man come to life talked little.", and so can you in french (3/4)

Comment: @PeterShor  ("L'homme revint à la vie." and "Lhomme revenu à la vie parla peu."). There is no problem with "The pupil was taken to the head." ("The pupil taken to the head was a girl.").   Don't think it is much different in French, it is not. A seemingly telling result is that given by the Google research "blow to kingdom come,*_NOUN blown to kingdom come": there is not a single result for the second expression. (4/4)